# UWP WebView equivalent shouldOverrideUrlLoading Android

Tags: c#, android, webview, win-universal-app

I would like to know the equivalent event for `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` in Android for a *`Universal Windows Platform WebView*` in `C#`. For what I have read I think is `webView.NavigationStarting`. Am I right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using Xamrin?

Comment: No, I am not using Xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 8.1 universal apps and WebBrowser:
Check [Navigating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigating%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event and navigate where you want with [Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff403407%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method (if you want to navigate somewhere else and "override" URL)

For UWP and WebView:
Right. With [NavigationStarting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting.aspx) you can check navigation event. And if you want to load another page use [Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigate.aspx) or NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage or else overrides

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I need!